# Exception notifier plugin not sending emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Trying to get Rails exception notifier plugin working. I've installed it in my app...

```
script/plugin install git://github.com/rails/exception_notification.git
```

Put this at the end of `environment.rb` outside of the `Rails::Initializer` call...

```
ExceptionNotifier.exception_recipients = %w(user@host.com)
ExceptionNotifier.sender_address = %("Error" <abc@xyz.com>)
ExceptionNotifier.email_prefix = "[Error] "
```

Added these to `development.rb`...

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = true
ActionMailer::Base.raise_delivery_errors = true
```

Added to `application_controller.rb`

```
include ExceptionNotifiable
local_addresses.clear
```

And added this to one of my actions for testing...

```
raise RuntimeError, "Generating an error"
```

When I hit the action the exception is raised but no email goes out. Looked in the development log. No sign of email activity.

I verified that I can send a test email in development, so email sending is configured correctly.

Answer (score 4):

*ExceptionNotifier* doesn't send error email because it considers your request as local. Try to change this config setting:

```
config.action_controller.consider_all_requests_local = false
```