# Exception Notification - How to Shut Off in Dev. Mode

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've been happily using exception notification up till now and never sent an email when running in development mode. Now, the gem seems to want to send me an email whenever an exception occurs -- particularly a routing error. Is there some config setting I'm missing? The dox seem to have dried up and blown away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming you have an initializer to set up your configuration, just wrap it in a conditional to check if it's in production mode:

```
if Rails.env.production?
  Whatever::Application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
    :email_prefix => "[Whatever] ",
    :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@example.com>},
    :exception_recipients => %w{exceptions@example.com}
end
```

Comment: d'oh. I remembered the previous version where stuff had to be stuck inside controllers and putting the configuration inside a conditional would cause all kinds of fuss. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Part 1: set up different configurations for ExceptionNotifier in your config/environments/environment_name.rb files.  For example, in config/environments/development.rb, use something like this to send your notifications elsewhere, or to a black hole:

```
  YourApp::Application.configure do
    <other stuff>
    config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
      :email_prefix => "[YourApp - DEVELOPMENT:#{`hostname`}] ",
      :sender_address => %{"notifier" <notifier@#{`hostname`}>},
      :exception_recipients => %w{<some_bitbucket_email_address>}
  end
```

This way, your ExceptionNotifier is still configured in all environments.  If it isn't configured, any direct calls to

```
 ExceptionNotifier::Notifier.background_exception_notification(e).deliver
```

will throw exceptions, which could be undesired behavior inside a rescue block.

Part 2: try setting this config parameter:

```
config.consider_all_requests_local = true
```

I picked that up from the reverse question to this:  [Exception notifier plugin not sending emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1208253/exception-notifier-plugin-not-sending-emails?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

### Rails 3

Is better write the configuration in the production environment, look at my examle

```
APP::Application.configure do
...
..
.
config.middleware.use ExceptionNotifier,
                   :email_prefix => "[Error] ",
                   :sender_address => %{"Notificacion de error" <notifier@example.com>},
                   :exception_recipients => %w{addres1@email.com}
```